# Command 'nodejs' not found, but can be installed with: sudo apt install nodejs in ububtu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

installed node.js already but shows

Command `nodejs` not found, but can be installed with:

```
  sudo apt install nodejs
```

then tried, `sudo apt install nodejs`

and shows

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
nodejs is already the newest version (14.13.1-deb-1nodesource1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

but when I try to check node.js version, `$ nodejs -v`
it shows, Command `nodejs` not found, but can be installed with:

```
sudo apt install nodejs
```

Please help me to solve this error and properly see node.js version

Comment: you have to write `node -v` not `nodejs -v`

Answer (score 9):

The nodejs executable is called `node`, please run `node --version` to see if your installation works.

Comment: thank you google !!! And you who fed it !